Cauchy's theorem why emphasizing interior
I learned two typesof Cauchy's theorem in Stein and Shakarchi's book Complex analysis and quite confused about the descriptions of the second type.

Suppose $\Omega$ is convex and open, $f$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then for any closed curve $\gamma \subset \Omega$, the contour integral along the curve is zero. $\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z = 0$

It seems we try to get rid of the assumpsion of convexity, so the author loosely defined toy contour and stated that,

The important point is that for a toy contour $\gamma$ we easily have that
$\int_\gamma f(z)\mathrm{d}z = 0$
whenever $f$ is holomorphic in an open set that contains the contour $\gamma$
and its interior.

I am quite confused why we do not need to emphasize the interior in $1.$ while it needs to be stressed in $2.$

The assumption that $\Omega$ is convex in the first description implies that the interior of any closed curve $\gamma$ is also contained in $\Omega$, in particular $f$ is holomorphic there. In other words, it's not emphasized there because it's automatically true by the other assumptions.
Added: To see that the interior of $\gamma$ is fully inside $\Omega$, one could do this: Let $p$ be a point in the interior of $\gamma$. Draw any straight line through $p$. By the Jordan Curve Theorem, that line will intersect $\gamma$ at least once on one side and at least once on the other side of $p$. Since those two intersection points lie on $\gamma$, they are both in $\Omega$, by assumption. By convexity, so is $p$.

Why does the interior of any closed curve is contained in $\Omega$? Is there a theorem guaranteeing that?

@Andrew_Ren See addition.

a workaround to bypass JCT both for machinery purposes and because $\gamma$ need not be simple--  if $\gamma$ has an interior i.e. $\mathbb C- [\gamma]$ has more than one component (it always has a bounded component) select $p$ in the interior and draw a ray from $p$ to $\infty$, it must intersect $\gamma$'s image, $[\gamma]$, otherwise $p$ would be in both a bounded component (by construction) and the unbounded component (via path connectivity in $\mathbb C-[\gamma]$) which is impossible.  Now draw a ray running in the opposite direction (to complete the line) and get another intersection.

@user8675309: I thought that the fact that $\mathbb C \setminus [\gamma]$ always has one bounded component, for a sufficiently general type of $\gamma$, was the hardest part of the JCT.

@TorstenSchoeneberg -- I'm not following you here.  OP is asking about why the "interior" is not mentioned in (1.) for $\gamma$, a closed but not necessarily simple curve.  Since $\gamma$ is not simple per se in (1.), JCT cannot directly apply.  (I believe the "toy curves" mentioned in (2.) are a naive form of simple curves but that's a different matter.)  Multiple bounded components for $\mathbb C-[\gamma]$ are fine for (1.) and trivially if there is no bounded component then the "interior" is an empty set which is fine as well.
